# Getting error with conda install using custom channel to install from local tar file

Tags: macos, python-2.7, installation, conda

I'm trying to install PyAlgoTrade using a tar.gz file I downloaded from their [GitHub page](http://gbeced.github.io/pyalgotrade/downloads/) (it's not on Binstar).  I edited my .condarc file to include "- file://~/conda_repo".  Then I try to install, with the following results:

$ conda install PyAlgoTrade-0.16

Fetching package metadata: .Error: Could not find URL: 
file://~/conda_repo/osx-64/

$ ls ~/conda_repo/osx-64/

PyAlgoTrade-0.16.tar.gz

The ls results clearly show that the URL is correct.  I'm thinking that there is an extra environment / config setup that I'm missing and not finding in the conda documentation.  Any help in resolving this mystery would be appreciated.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You are making a few mistakes here. The first, and most important one, is that **the file you downloaded is not a conda package**.  So conda won't be able to install it.  It looks like it is a Python package, so you can install it with pip: `pip install PyAlgoTrade-0.16.tar.gz`.

---

To clarify some other mistakes you made:

File urls cannot contain `~`. Use the full path to your home directory.  Also note that if this were a conda package, you would need to run `conda index` on that directory to do make a local repo like this. And (again, if it were), an easier way would be to `conda install downloaded-conda-package.tar.bz2` (that is, run `conda install` on the downloaded file directly).

Comment: Thanks for responding.  I figured I was missing something fundamental.  I did a conda deep dive this morning and figured out how to create a conda package by creating a conda-recipe.  It's all good now.